# Form of select tags, I want to fire an event if any of them change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with 18 different questions, each one has a select field with some options.

My goal is that any time a user opens the `select` field and picks an `option`, I want to do an AJAX call.

My form's id is `#new-survey`, is there any way to put a watcher on the child elements (the `select` menus) or something similar to watch all of those fields?

Note: Also using jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure javascript:

```
var form = document.getElementById("new-survey");
var selects = form.getElementsByTagName("SELECT");

for (var i=0; i< selects.length; i++) {
     selects[i].setAttribute("onchange", domyajax);
}

function domyajax(e) {
 /// ajax content in here
}
```

in jquery:

```
$("#new-survey").find("select").change(function(){
     // do something with $(this);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the jquery `each` method:

```
$('#new-survey select').each(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
       ...
    });
});
```

Comment: And that makes jquery solutions to a javascript question irrelevant?

Comment: That's fine, I'm using jQuery. Thanks @tomaroo

Comment: Why use `each`? jQuery supports bindings on multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#new-survey").find("select").change(function () {
    alert("something changed");
});
```

It will find all the `select`'s within `#new-survey` and bind a change event to them.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/K6qsB/)